# If either of the files exist then send email alert in bash shell script

Tags: linux, shell, email, unix

Trying to mock a little shell script.. There is a process that already exists which creates one of the two files (i.e, file1 or file2). My goal is to be able to send email alert depending on which file is created.

For example, if file1 exists then send email to John, David, Smith stating that file1 was created. If file2 exists then send an email to the same group of people (John, David, Smith ) stating that file2 was created.

If I write a simple if-else it will work but I will need to repeat some parts of the code which I am trying to avoid.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="file1"
if [ -f "$file1" ]
    then
        send email to three people mentioned 
    else
        send email to three people mentioned saying file2 was created since it always creates two files 
    fi
}
```

Here I am trying to construct a script in a better way and also I don't want to repeat "send email..." commands three times because I may need to add more people into the list in the future.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though I can't name any off the top of my head, there are packages already available that will monitor directories for changes and generate various kinds of alerts.  Have you tried searching the Internet for "directory monitor"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

userlist="$HOME/myusers.cfg" # one user per line

function send_alert {
   while read -r user comment; do
      echo "my command to send to ${user}"
      echo "subject=$1"
      echo "Content=Hello ${comment}\n$2"
   done < "${userlist}"
}

file="file1"
if [ -f "$file1" ]; then
   send_alert "My subject" "Content: ${file1} exists."
else
   send_alert "My subject" "Content: ${file2} exists."
fi
```

I added an optional field comment in the myusers.cfg, so you can add some comment after a space (name person, something).
You can adjust send_alert for more business rules, such as only send once an hour an alert, only send during working hours except for the person on night shift, whatever.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will run it through to see if I can tied to my requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function block that send a mail to a desired list of people.Call the function from either of the case

Comment: *directory monitor* - I am not sure how I can construct something to satisfy my needs with this though

Comment: I am afraid I dont haven't used function which I can call from either case. It seems to me it will be easier to do that way. Is there any template which I can use that will be able to send alert depending of if either of the file ( file1/file2) exist? appreciated.